# Converting string in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz format to DateTime

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime

I am receiving a JSON DateTime from a web service in the following format

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz`

For example:

`2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00`

However, I am unable to convert this into a DateTime object. I have tried the following:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date2 = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Both of these lines throw the `System.FormatException` exception with the message:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can I parse `2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00` as a DateTime object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the "zzz" expects a sign on the timezone.

This will work.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-04-18T15:09:21 +01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss zzz",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.Dump();
```

So add a plus sign.

```
var dt="2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00";
dt.Insert(20,"+").Dump();
```

Comment: Actually, a +... or a - depending of desired TimeZone, of course

Answer (score 2):

Dmitriy has the right answer, from [The "zzz" custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?#zzzSpecifier) documentation;

> The offset is ***always*** displayed with a leading sign. A plus sign (`+`)
>   indicates hours ahead of UTC, and a minus sign (`-`) indicates hours
>   behind UTC. A single-digit offset is formatted with a leading zero.

If your string is *always* in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss HH:mm` format, you *have to* manipulate it if you wanna parse it to `DateTimeOffset`.

I would suggest to you split your string with a white space, call `DateTime.Parse` and `TimeSpan.Parse` on those strings and use those values in a [`DateTimeOffset(DateTime, TimeSpan)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which;

> Initializes a new instance of the `DateTimeOffset` structure using the
>   specified `DateTime` value and `offset`.

```
var str = "2016-04-18T15:09:21 01:00";
var parts = str.Split(' ');
var date = DateTime.Parse(parts[0]);
var offset = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[1]);
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(date, offset);
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{18.04.2016 15:09:21 +01:00}` and you can use it's `DateTime`, `LocalDateTime` or `UtcDateTime` properties whichever you want.

[image]